# How to round to the next 1000 value?

Tags: elixir

I want to round to the next 1000 value, always rounding up.

Example inputs:

```
1 -> 1000
440 -> 1000
1001 -> 2000
14399 -> 15000
108 030 -> 109 000
```

I can only find a Float.ceil function which is not relevant for me.

Answer (score 7):

Ciel is correct, you need to add some math to it.

```
ceil(number/1000)*1000
```

Edit: To round to the nearest number you want

```
 ceil(number/n)*n //n = number to round to
```

Answer (score 3):

Train's answer is great (duly upvoted). You could also make a function, to allow you to specify the rounding target:

```elixir
def ceil_nearest(num, target), do: ceil(num/target)*target
```

Then:

```elixir
ceil_nearest(14399, 1000) # 15000
ceil_nearest(14399, 500)  # 14500
```

Comment: Great answer and reusable if the same function is used in more than one area.